# Separating column into two separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `name`.  There are entries such-as:

```
Smith, John
Smith, Joe
One whole entry
```

I need them separated into two columns as this:

```
LastName        | FirstName
---------------------------
Smith           | John
Smith           | Joe
One whole entry |
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT left(name, CHARINDEX(', ', name)) as LastName FROM LookUps
```

I've tried the following above, but it's displaying the following comma (e.g. *Smith,*). I need it to remove this following comma, but also display the full information for those entries without a comma.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    case when charindex(',',name) > 0 
            then left(name, charindex(',',name)-1 ) 
            else name end,
    case when charindex(',',name) > 0 
            then ltrim(substring(name, charindex(',',name)+1, len(name) )) 
            else null end   
from yourtable
```

Comment: Thank you podiluska; that does EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Another way;

```
select
  left(name, charindex(',', name + ',', 1) - 1) as lastname,
  ltrim(substring(name,  charindex(',', name + ',', 1) + 1, len(name))) as firstname
```